cloudflare worker not triggered on a route
I have a cloudflare worker but it's not triggered on a route I configured.
routes = [
{ pattern = "myapp/resources-v2/*", zone_id = "abc123"}
]

I can see the worker in the domain's settings in cloudflare under the "workers routes" tab. This tells me that the zone_id at least is right.
As for the pattern, I can see the browser calling https://myapp/resources-v2/very long/list/of/resources/?query-params=im-stuck-and-need-help in the developers' console.
And finally, when I go directly to the worker's address at*.workers.dev I can see logs appearing in cloudflare. So the worker is deployed.
I don't know what I can verify besides these 3 things I mentioned above.
Can someone please give me a hint?
Thanks kindly

You can try the following:

make sure that your domain myapp dns record is configured as proxied (with the orange cloud icon enabled in the DNS settings). If it is not proxied, it means the request will not go through Cloudflare and will not trigger the worker;
you can use Cloudflare Trace to check how the request goes through Cloudflare;
try using a more general pattern, like *myapp/*;

